# Is it possible to make navigation drawer inside fragment instead of Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have home activity which open the next view for different profile.

1. For School
2. For College
3. For Office
4. For Apartment

in all these view i want using the navigation drawer which is inside the fragment not activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside NavigationDrawerFragment create setMenu method

```
public void setMenu(String[] menu) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            menu);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

When you switch your fragments use this switch case

```
int fragmentType = position;

        final int FRAGMENT_1 = 0;
        final int FRAGMENT_2 = 1;
        final int FRAGMENT_3 = 2;

        switch (fragmentType) {
            case FRAGMENT_1:
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setMenu(new String[]{"FRAGMENT_1  Section 1",
                        "FRAGMENT_1 Section 2",
                        "FRAGMENT_1 Section 3"
                });
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_2:
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setMenu(new String[]{"FRAGMENT_2  Section 1",
                        "FRAGMENT_2 Section 2",
                        "FRAGMENT_2 Section 3"
                });
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_3:
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setMenu(new String[]{"FRAGMENT_3 Section 1",
                        "FRAGMENT_3 Section 2",
                        "FRAGMENT_3 Section 3"
                });
                break;

        }
    }
```

As you see i change menu based ob the current fragment type.

Default menu

[image]

When i switched the fragment

[image]

Comment: I want like Fragment class extends NavigationDrawer, Means base class is fragment which has Navigation Drawer not Activity. This is already know and used ....

Comment: But here you have base fragment with all Navigation Drawer Logic, you use activity only to show it.

Comment: That i used...    that's why i asked is it possible to use only fragment as base and all logic also using fragment only....    but activity only to start application... not for navigation drawer...

Comment: Ok, don't get this, then the answer is definite NO. You can't use fragments without activity.

Comment: Is it also correct .. we can't use fragment without Activity... but i have activity that has fragment which has concept of Navigation Drawer.